# Passing multiple parameters to query function (useQuery) from React-Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I want to execute the `getUsers` function using `useQuery` from react-query.
The `useQuery` function has 3 parameters but I don't know what is the syntax to pass them, the code below doesn't work, nothing appears on the page

```
  const { isLoading, isError, data } = useQuery(
    ["getUsers"],
    getUsers(
      location?.state?.code || cookies.get("code"),
      cookies.get("accessToken"),
      cookies.get("expirationDate")
    )
  );
```

The `getUsers` function is below :

```
import axios from "axios";

export default async function getUsers(code, accessToken, expirationDate) {
  return axios.post(`${import.meta.env.VITE_NAME_API_URL}/get-users`, {
    code,
    accessToken,
    expirationDate,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass parameters to some function that is used by useQuery you need to specify them in the dependency array.

React Query Dependent Queries Documentation: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/dependent-queries?from=reactQueryV3&original=https%3A%2F%2Freact-query-v3.tanstack.com%2Fguides%2Fdependent-queries

**Documentations example:**

```js
const { data: user } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['user', email],
  queryFn: getUserByEmail,
})
```

**Your exmaple:**

```js
    const code = location?.state?.code || cookies.get("code")
    const accessToken = cookies.get("accessToken")
    const expDate = cookies.get("expirationDate")

     const { isLoading, isError, data } = useQuery(
    ["getUsers", code, accessToken, expDate],
    getUsers(
      code,
      accessToken,
      expDate
    )
  );
```

Comment: The query key is not a dependency array. It serves a different purpose entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The `useQuery` hook expects you to provide (at least) 2 things. A query key (the parameters that should be used to cache/fetch the data), and an async function which will receive the query key and should return the result of the query.

In your example you have an async function which takes a bunch of parameters, but not a query key. So you'll want to wrap that function in a query function that you can pass to `useQuery`.

e.g.

```js
  const code = location?.state?.code || cookies.get("code")
  const accessToken = cookies.get("accessToken")
  const expDate = cookies.get("expirationDate")

  const { isLoading, isError, data } = useQuery(
    ["getUsers", code, accessToken, expirationDate],
    ({queryKey: [queryType, ...params]}) => getUsers(...params)
  );
```

Comment: I have 2 errors : ```react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Me. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks``` and ```react-dom.development.js:15162 Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.```

Comment: Don't put your useQuery call inside a conditional or a loop.

Comment: It's not inside these